# Is trajectory stabilization of a robot with a hydroelastic contact model possible with a Finite Horizon Linear Quadratic Regulator?

Tags: python, drake

We are trying to track the trajectory of a brachiation robot([GitHub link](https://github.com/dfki-ric-underactuated-lab/acromonk)) as it brachiates along a ladder, with hydroelastic contact model enabled. We have the optimized reference trajectories for generalized positions, and also the optimal input sequence. We already have a PID controller that tracks the trajectory, but it requires a lot of tuning, and we believe that the TVLQR will be more robust to disturbances, and easier to tune.

We tried using the FiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulator() as a feedback control method, but got the following error:

```
SystemExit: Failure at systems/controllers/finite_horizon_linear_quadratic_regulator.cc:62 in RiccatiSystem(): condition 'context_->has_only_continuous_state()' failed.
```

It is true that our plant context has one continuous state(the input) and one discrete state group with 8 states(generalized positions and velocities) in it. What we would like to ask is if there is any other way to use the Finite Horizon Linear Quadratic Regulator as a trajectory stabilizer for a robot simulation with hydroelastic contact enabled. If not, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your understanding is correct. The code as written doesn't quite support your case.

Implementing finite-horizon LQR for (simple) discrete-time systems is actually easier than for continuous-time systems.  Unfortunately, I did the continuous-time first, and left a [TODO](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/82d8460973cd39defac2b6cee5d696a860237973/systems/controllers/finite_horizon_linear_quadratic_regulator.h#L102) to finish the discrete-time version.  It would require implementing the Riccati difference equation found [here](https://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/lqr.html#section3).

We do have a [problem on iLQR in the underactuated notes](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Underactuated-2ed1518a-973b-4145-bd62-1768b49956a8/project/2041fb46-1aaa-4996-8a52-234b5b6029f6/%2Filqr_driving.ipynb) which might get you pretty close.  Otherwise I'll try to implement it soon.  But contributions are always welcome!